# POPULATION ISSUE: Mongoose/Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to have each record attached to a user who created it,
and every user have their records attached.
Here are my schemas:

1.The Records schema:

```
            const mongoose = require('mongoose')
           const RecordsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
                {
  
           Title: { type: String, required: true },
           postedby:[{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'user'
           }],
         Author: { type: String, required: true},
          ISBN: { type: String, required: true },
          Review: { type: String },
          SelectedFile: { type: String },
         Likes: { type: Number, default:0},
         Date: { type: Date, default: Date.now()}
          });

        module.exports = Records = mongoose.model('record', RecordsSchema', 'record');`
```

Here is the The user Schema:

```
         const mongoose = require('mongoose')
         const  userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
           {
        username: { type: String},
        email: { type: String, required: true ,unique:true},
        records:[{
        type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'record' }],
      password: { type: String, required: true},
       Date: { type: Date, default: Date.now(), immutable: true }
         });
 
        module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema,'user');
```

The express route for getting a record:

```
router.get('/postedby/', (req, res) => {

    Records.find(req.params.id)
    .populate('postedby')
    .exec()
   .then(post =>{
     if (!post) {
     return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Add Posts' });
   }
 
  else return res.json(post);
  
  }).catch (err => console.error(err))
 
});
```

Result of the route:

```
       {
       "postedby": [],
       "Likes": 0,
       "_id": "5fed8c12a4fb2c1e98ef09f6",
       "Title": "New Age",
       "Author": "Situma Prisco",
       "ISBN": "23422",
       "SelectedFile": "",
       "Review": "",
       "Date": "2020-12-31T08:30:10.321Z",
       "__v": 0
        },
```

I'm getting a blank Array on the populated user field(posteddby) .
Please help, What am I doing wrong? And yes, i do have a User Logged in

Answer (score 0):

You are too close.

In your schema definition, `postedby` field itself is an array. Hence you can simply define it like :

```
postedby:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  }]
```

Make sure that the ObjectID is stored properly in the `postedby` array.

Also, you are trying to find a single record based on the ID, hence you can use `findById(req.params.id)` or `findOne({_id:req.params.id})` which would return a single document.

Comment: Hey Pranesh, thank you for responding.However, the array bracket doesn't make any difference.The find method,also, returns the same result, so in the end, i still have a blank array

Comment: @Clarasituma Can you please make sure whether the objectId is stored properly in the `postedby` array?

Comment: @PraneshAS...It is: [{"records":[],"_id":"5ff5652d4be62c4a1ce3efc5","Date":"2021-01-06T07:17:46.643Z","username":"clara","email":"cnsituma@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$iuZXVBzRQuE3IKPKMAa380lZo6AaK5lzr9P956HSW","__v":0}]

Comment: @Clarasituma This is not the `record` model. The one you shared is the `user` model. But the `postedby` field resides in the `record` schema. Please check whether the id is stored there.

Comment: How exactly do I do that? Because all there is a blank array